# Proj4 WKT - Cartesian with origin to EPSG900913

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, well-known-text

I'm converting wgs84 to cartesian with origin using simple function in c#

```
public static double[] LL_TO_XY(double latitude, double longitude, double originLatitude, double originLongitude)
    {

            //var xx,yy,r,ct,st,angle;
        double xx;
        double yy;
        double r;
        double ct;
        double st;
        double angle;
        double rotation_angle_degs = 0;
        double xoffset_mtrs = 0;
        double yoffset_mtrs = 0;
        double pxpos_mtrs;
        double pypos_mtrs;
        double[] p = new double[2];


            angle = DEG_TO_RADIANS(rotation_angle_degs);



        xx = (longitude - originLongitude)*METERS_DEGLON(originLatitude);
        yy = (latitude - originLatitude)*METERS_DEGLAT(originLatitude);

                r = Mathd.Sqrt(xx*xx + yy*yy);

                /* alert('LL_TO_XY: xx=' + xx + ' yy=' + yy + ' r=' + r);
    return false;*/

                //if(r)
                //{
                    ct = xx/r;
                    st = yy/r;
                    xx = r * ( (ct * Mathd.Cos(angle)) + (st * Mathd.Sin(angle)) );
            yy = r * ( (st * Mathd.Cos(angle)) - (ct * Mathd.Sin(angle)) );
                //}
                pxpos_mtrs = xx + xoffset_mtrs;
                pypos_mtrs = yy + yoffset_mtrs;

        p [0] = pxpos_mtrs;
        p [1] = pypos_mtrs;
        return p;


    }
```

Now I want to convert these cartesian values into EPSG900913. I can use proj4 for this so I think it should be better.

I know that to convert from WGS84 to EPSG900913 I need to define WKT for proj4 like this:

```
private static string wktEPSG900913 =
    "PROJCS[\"WGS84 / Simple Mercator\", " +
    "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\", " +
    "DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\", SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\", 6378137.0, 298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]], " +
    "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]]," +
    "PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0.0, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]], " +
    "UNIT[\"degree\",0.017453292519943295], " +
    "AXIS[\"Longitude\", EAST], AXIS[\"Latitude\", NORTH]," +
    "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]], " +
    "PROJECTION[\"Mercator_1SP\"]," +
    "PARAMETER[\"semi_minor\", 6378137.0], " +
    "PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0.0], " +
    "PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\", 0.0], " +
    "PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",1.0], " +
    "PARAMETER[\"false_easting\", 0.0], " +
    "PARAMETER[\"false_northing\", 0.0]," +
    "UNIT[\"m\", 1.0], " +
    "AXIS[\"x\", EAST], AXIS[\"y\", NORTH]," +
    "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"900913\"]]";
```

What WKT I need to use to convert from cartesian with origin to EPSG900913?